# Match a string with two different fixed lengths with preg_match

Tags: php, regex

Is it possible to match a string of two different lengths with `preg_match`? And if yes, how?

I’m looking for something like this:

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{13|25}$/", $string);
```

As in, return true if `$string` las a length of exactly either 13 **or** 25 characters.

P.S.: I know that should be `{13,25}` — `{min,max}` —, but I’m not interested in matching within an interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know your question was about doing it with regex, but it's generally best practice to avoid regex whenever possible.  A few reasons why:

- You should benchmark to be certain, but in most cases, built-in functions will out-perform regex.
- Regex is not (thoroughly) understood by a lot of coders
- Regex is usually less flexible as far as throwing new "business rules" / requirements into the mix. For example, what if you needed to add in a requirement to do something if the length is 13, and something different if it's 25? Or maybe do something if it's right chars but wrong length?  You will not be able to code for these things with regex alone (*The solution I present below doesn't address these "what ifs" either but the difference here is that you now have ability to separate the stuff as needed*)

So here is a non-regex approach.

```
if ( in_array(strlen($string),array(13,25)) && ctype_alnum($string) ) {
  // good
} else {
  // bad
}
```

Comment: Even for specific cases as this one? I can see the difference if you have to match against something like `/^[a-z0-9]*/i`, but if the string’s length is fixed?

Comment: @Alex it's not that regex *can't* do the job in your situation, it's more a matter of principle and best practice whether or not to use regex in general. In general, built-in functions will perform better, and in general, non-regex solutions are more flexible and easier to understand, as far as other coders touching it, business requirements changing, etc.

Comment: @Alex don't get me wrong.. I'm a huge fan of regex. It's downright sexy. But honestly, it's a super powerful tool with a very narrow niche for what it's overall useful for, from a best practice PoV

Answer (score 4):

This is a fast way:

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{13}([a-zA-Z0-9]{12})?$/', $string);
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9]{13}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{25})$/", $string);
```

- `([a-zA-Z0-9]{13}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{25}` alternation matches either of length 13 or 25

**Example** : http://regex101.com/r/bJ9vV5/1